# User input error checking using text file in Java

Tags: java

I have a text file with all room numbers in my school. I then have code that asks for the room number of the student's class. kb is the user input scanner and roomnos is the text file scanner. This is the code:

```
String room = null;
boolean invalid = true;
while(invalid)
{
    System.out.println("What is the room number of your class?");
    room = kb.nextLine();
    while(roomnos.hasNext())
    {
        String roomno = roomnos.nextLine();
        if(room.equals(roomno))
            invalid = false;
    }
    if(invalid == true)
    {
        System.out.println("The room number you've given is invalid.");
    }
}
```

The code works if the first room number given by the user is valid. However, if the user inputs an invalid room number, the loop does not stop, that is, it says the room number is invalid and asks for the room number again and again, even if the room number is valid. What I think is that the hasNext() in the nested while loop does not restart and go back to the beginning of the file and hence, cannot search for the room number during the next loops of the bigger while loop. Whatever the problem is, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out myself. The problem was what I thought, the scanner of the file with the room numbers wasn't restarting and so the inner while loop was not functioning if the first input from the user was invalid. The following code fixed the problem:

```
String room = null;
boolean invalid = true;
while(invalid)
{
    System.out.println("What is the room number of your class?");
    room = kb.nextLine();
    roomnos = new Scanner(new File("/*file location*/"));
    while(roomnos.hasNext())
    {
        String roomno = roomnos.nextLine();
        if(room.equals(roomno))
            invalid = false;
    }
    if(invalid == true)
    {
        System.out.println("The room number you've given is invalid.");
    }
    roomnos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check for invalid input happens outside of the while-loop *and* the loop has no breaking condition at all. Move the check inside of the loop and then add a breaking condition to leave the loop at some time.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. By check do you mean the if statement that checks for the boolean 'invalid' and prints that the room number is invalid? Because I thought it should be outside the inner while loop so that the loop can go through each line of the text file before seeing if the room number is invalid. Also, where exactly do I put the break? Is one inside the inner while loop enough?

Answer (score 0):

i would modify the code in this way, adding a value that mean how many line you may got.

```
String room = null;
boolean invalid = true;
int maxline = 100;//i suppose

while(invalid)
{
    int lineCounter=0;
    System.out.println("What is the room number of your class?");
    room = kb.nextLine();
    while(roomnos.hasNext())
    {
        lineCounter++;
        String roomno = roomnos.nextLine();
        if(room.equals(roomno))
            invalid = false;
        if(lineCounter>maxline)
            break;
    }
    if(invalid == true)
    {
        System.out.println("The room number you've given is invalid.");
    }
}
```

the motivation because your code does not work is that a file got virtually infite lines to read, so you must break at certain point.

Comment: try to debug, or at least use some "System.out.print" to see the value of the variables in certain points so you can get the error